# Is there a way to reload my app without window.location.reload() and ngOnInit()?

Tags: javascript, angular, browser, angular-router

Is there any way to reload my Angular 11 app without window.location.reload() and ngOnInit()?

window.location.reload() makes Chrome reload the tab which is not my desired outcome. And ngOnInit() causes some wierd bugs in my app.

I would like to have something similar to window.location.reload() but that doesn't refresh the Chrome tab.

Any solutions to this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: a hacky responsive design. I've made a grid game and want to create a custom grid size based on screen width. it works if you arrive the site for the first time. now im implementing a @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event']) so that when the user shrinks the browser the grid "refreshes". Right now im using ngOnInit but it causes some weird bugs in the grid..

Comment: I see. I would probably create a function to do the resize afterViewInit and after the resize event fires. The DOM won't be ready during onInit, which may be what's causing issues for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like without any data you approach is wrong, you can use ngAfterViewInit or one of the life cycle hooks with element refresh.  however if you are trying to refresh data on the screen you should look at service binding so that the data is "reactive".

you can use behavior subject or subject binding but it makes your data as a subscribed event so its updated without redrawing the viewport.

however without any type of code or anything this is only speculation.